# Python Openpyxl doesn't write to spreadsheet

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I'm trying to automate a task where it's get's the users location and turns them to latitude and longitude and write them to spreadsheet which I did. But it doesn't write anything to the spreadsheet. I tried adding the save too, another for loop and even to set it to write only but that didn't workout. Here is my code:

```
# Problem: Get for all locations the latitude and longitude
# Solution: loop through all of them turn them into geolocation values and write them back to spreadsheet. This is the code:

# 1. Import modules
import openpyxl

import os
import geocoder
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
# 2. Set up spread sheet
print('Opening workbook...')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/user/Downloads/plswork.xlsx', )
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('results')
sheet = wb.active

# 3. Loop through all data
print('Reading rows...')

for row in range(3, sheet.max_row + 1):
    country = sheet['E' + str(row)].value
    city =  sheet['F' + str(row)].value
    both = country + ' ' + city
    print both
# 4. Convert into location
    g = geocoder.google(both)
    location = g.latlng
    print location
# 5. Write to spreadsheet 
    sheet['K' + str(row)] = str(location) 
  
print('Saving...')
wb.save('plswork.xlsx')
print('Saved..')
```

[image: This is the excel spreadsheet. Due to personal data the content is censored!]

This is the excel spreadsheet. Due to personal data the content is censored!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't test this easily, but in the code you posted is the indent on the line below commen '5 Write to spreadsheet' correct? If it is correct then this line isn't in the loop, it is executed only once. I expect you should indent this line so it is in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion let me check

Comment: Hey it works! silly newbie mistake by me. Thanks @barny a lot